# Can I finish an animation without the animating itself

Tags: android, animation

If I have an animation like this

`textView.animate().translationY(-translationY * 0.32f).scaleX(0.7f).scaleY(0.7f);`

is it possible to directly "end" the animation so that the user won't see the movement of the textview but its final position will be the translated and shifted one?

I do not want to use another textview. Only some code pathes do not need the animation itself but the end position directly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly set the required properties on the `View` without starting an animation:

```
textView.setTranslationY(-translationY * 0.32f);
textView.setScaleX(0.7f);
textView.setScaleY(0.7f);
```

Or you can set the duration to a very small value:

```
textView.animate().translationY(-translationY *0.32f).scaleX(0.7f).scaleY(0.7f).setDuration(1);
```